# Using Other User's Data to estimate probability of clicking a link

Tags: probability

Say I have users and a list of links they've clicked

For example, user 1 has clicked links 3,4,5 and user 2 has clicked links 4,5,6.  How would you go about calculating the probability that user 1 will click link 6 if it is shown to them?

Comment: as all clicks are potentially completely independent of each other, I think there needs to be more detail added.

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is to find all the other users that have been shown link 6 and compute the fraction of them that clicked on it.  That corresponds to assuming all your users behave similarly.  The next level is to look at the correlations between users clicking on links and find users who click the same links as user 1, then compute the faction of those who clicked on link 6.  Further on, you can examine their whole Facebook page, zip code, car they own, etc.  and try to improve your prediction.  Many companies have whole departments devoted to this.  You need to make your question much more specific.

Comment: like how many links etc.